# Nested ternaries, can't spot the error

Tags: ssis, nested, ternary-operator

I have this nested ternary expression in SSIS that I can't seem to get to work, my eyes are about to come out of my skull.

```
FINDSTRING(TRIM(f3),"BASICS",1) != 0 ? (UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "F" ? @[User::FallBasicsEntityId] : (UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "S" ? @[User::SpringBasicsEntityId] : @[user::BasicsEntityId])) : (UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "F" ? @[user::FallEntityId] : (UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "S" ? @[user::SpringEntityId] : @[user::DefaultEntityId]))
```

Here's an "indented" version:

```
FINDSTRING(TRIM(f3),"BASICS",1) != 0 
    ? (
        UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "F" 
        ? @[User::FallBasicsEntityId] 
        : (
            UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "S" 
            ? @[User::SpringBasicsEntityId] 
            : @[user::BasicsEntityId]
          )
      ) 

    : (
        UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "F" 
        ? @[user::FallEntityId] 
        : (
            UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(f3),1)) == "S" 
            ? @[user::SpringEntityId] 
            : @[user::DefaultEntityId]
          )
      )
```

What am I missing? It looks to me like the parentheses are balanced and properly placed.. or are they?

I'm about to ditch this and resort to a script component... it seems to me such an expression would be easier to maintain with C# code...

Comment: What are you missing? A description of what the input/output should be. =;)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are balanced; the problem is that `user` is not the same as `User`.